# What happens if you do not allow time for an exothermic reaction to cool down?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry

I realise I did not give some time for the chemicals (which are releasing heat during an exothermic reaction) to cool down first and instead, I added another chemical substance to the reaction mixture immediately. Is it a red flag that I might lose some of my products and get a lower percentage yield? The experiment that I will be doing is Jacobsen's ligand asymmetric synthesis.

Comment: You burn your fingers when manipulating the flask ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the reaction, some are more temperature sensitive than others. You might get a slightly reduced yield or, at the other end of the spectrum, a runaway reaction leading to a redecorated fumehood.

For the Jacobsen asymmetric epoxidation this quote from the Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobsen_epoxidation) seems relevant:

> The degree of enantioselectivity depends on numerous factors, namely the structure of the alkene, the nature of the axial donor ligand on the active oxomanganese species and **the reaction temperature**.

So at the least you'll get reduced enantioselectivity. For other reactions (e.g. lithium-halogen exchange) getting the temperature wrong can generate completely different products than the one you were trying for.